# R-package dll not generated during installation

Tags: r, r-package, building

I am writing an example of an R-package that uses C++ to call a C-function from an external library (I used the chron.dll from the R-package chron).
The version of R is R-4.2.2. On my machine (Windows 10) rtools42 is installed in C:/Program Files aka C:/PROGRA~1.
Since this is not the standard location I am running

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste("C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/bin/", Sys.getenv("PATH"), sep=";"))
Sys.setenv(BINPREF = "C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/")
```

prior to the build. Then I check the build with devtools::check() and it seems that compilation and linking works but the installation
fails. The 00install.out file is as follows:

```
* installing *source* package 'PackageExample' ...
** using staged installation
** libs
C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../chron/include -I. -I'C:/Users/JohnDoe/PROJECTS/R/libraries/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../chron/include -I. -I'C:/Users/JohnDoe/PROJECTS/R/libraries/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c callchron.cpp -o callchron.o
C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../chron/include -I. -I'C:/Users/JohnDoe/PROJECTS/R/libraries/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c matrix.cpp -o matrix.o
C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../chron/include -I. -I'C:/Users/JohnDoe/PROJECTS/R/libraries/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG -I../chron/include -I. -I'C:/Users/JohnDoe/PROJECTS/R/libraries/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c vector.cpp -o vector.o
C:/PROGRA~1/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PackageExample.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o callchron.o matrix.o rcpp_hello_world.o vector.o -L../chron/libs/x64 -lchron -LC:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/Programme/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/JohnDoe/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpg9Wn7W/file43d46e066097/PackageExample.Rcheck/00LOCK-PACKAG~1/00new/PackageExample/libs/x64
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Reading Tests.R.
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: loading of pakckage or namespace 'PackageExample' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...): failed
cannot load shared object 'C:/Users/JohnDoe/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpg9Wn7W/file43d46e066097/PackageExample.Rcheck/00LOCK-PACKAG~1/00new/PackageExample/libs/x64/PackageExample.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  the referenced module was not found.

Error: loading failed
Execution terminated
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/JohnDoe/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpg9Wn7W/file43d46e066097/PackageExample.Rcheck/PackageExample'
```

(Some error messages translatd from German).
Interestingly the folder
C:/Users/JohnDoe/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpg9Wn7W/
contains files foo.dll, foo.o.

It looks like the PackageExample.dll is not put into

```
'C:/Users/JohnDoe/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmpg9Wn7W/file43d46e066097/PackageExample.Rcheck/00LOCK- PACKAG~1/00new/PackageExample/libs/x64/
```

and instead foo.dll and foo.o are generated. What might be the problem?